# Microsoft Graph: How to get all SharePoint sites for the current user (including Group sites)

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

When creating an Office Group a SharePoint Online site is created as well. (A site which is not listed in SharePoint Online Central Administration.)

How can I get a list of all such Group sites from Microsoft Graph for the current user? (I explicitly do *not* want to use the SharePoint Search API as it currently does *not* return all SharePoint sites belonging to Groups.)

Basically I want to get a list of all SharePoint sites the current user has access to - including classic and modern sites, while NOT using the SharePoint Search API. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*

Above Graph API will return  all site collection based on current user.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option you have is merging the result of these two:

1. Get all O365 groups for the user from /me/joinedGroups, filtering for unified type from the beta endpoint
2. Use search to find all classic SharePoint sites for the user

As far as I remember - there has never been an option to get all sites (site collections) for a given user from the SharePoint API without using search. It would be cool to have a joinedSites method returning all SharePoint sites for the user in GraphAPI.

For admins, you have now a consolidated list of all SharePoint site collections (classic and modern) on the new SharePoint Admin Center that is available in Preview on tenants that have preview features enabled.